# Discord.py Rewrite gathering list of all commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get a list of all the commands within my Discord bot in rewrite. I am using Python 3.6 to write this

I have tried to print a list of the commands by doing
`print(bot.commands)`
This only provided me with the following return:

`{<discord.ext.commands.core.Command object at 0x00000209EE6AD4E0>, <discord.ext.commands.core.Command object at 0x00000209EE6AD470>}`

I expect the usual output to be `clear()`, as that is the only command that I have programmed within the bot so far, the command works as expected. But it only prints the above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.

````
@bot.command(name="help", description="Returns all commands available")
async def help(ctx):
    helptext = "```"
    for command in self.bot.commands:
        helptext+=f"{command}\n"
    helptext+="```"
    await ctx.send(helptext)
````

Comment: Why does the `@bot.command` have `name="help", description="Returns all commands available"`. Is that important to the code or not, is that how it gets a list of all the commands?

Comment: The name perimeter is what the user will enter, for example !help, the description can be returned with the commands if you choose to do so, makes it easier.

Comment: how do i get the commands from a particular cog?

Comment: @StatTrakDiamondSword https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916630/list-the-commands-in-a-discord-py-cog/66917144#66917144

Comment: the name is `help` but the command name is `help`? Why would you put a `name="help"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
@commands.command(help = "Blah")
async def l1(self,ctx):
    commands = [c.name for c in self.client.commands]
    print(commands)
```

What you are getting is the command object, so if you want the name of the command you can get the name as `Command.name`.

Reference : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.name

Answer (score 0):

Those are the `Command` objects that your bot has.  The reason there are two is because your bot has a built-in `help` command that does exactly what you're looking for.  If your `clear` command was

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    "A command for clearing stuff"
    pass
```

then running `!help` would give you the output

```
 No Category:
  help  Shows this message.
  clear A command for clearing stuff

Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

Answer (score -1):

### Im really late but I wanted to share this.

#### Adding onto akiva and damaredayo's response, here is a basic command that will get all commands in cogs **and** main files.

```
@bot.command()
async def commandcount(ctx):
  counter = 0
  for command in bot.commands:
    counter += 1
  await ctx.send(f"There are `{counter}` commands!")
```

Comment: While valid, it, unfortunately, doesn't answer the question.