# List the Commands in a discord.py Cog

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

With discord.py, you can list the commands of a bot. This is best exemplified here:

```py
x = []
for y in client.commands:
    x.append(y.name)
print(x)
```

How would one do this with a specific cog?

Answer (score 2):

You can check which cog the command belongs with [`Command.cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.cog). Note that this will be `None` if the command does not belong to a cog.

**cog.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('bar')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

**bot.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client.load_extension('cog')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

x = []
for y in client.commands:
    if y.cog and y.cog.qualified_name == 'Test':
        x.append(y.name)
print(x)

client.run('token')
```

Comment: Thanks! It's 5AM in the morning, so I'll try this out in the morning. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried everything. Didn't know there was an attribute called `qualified_name`