# Getting the commands in a cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there any way to get all the commands in a cog??? I am trying to make a help command but I don't know how to get the commands in a certain cog, I have tried things like:

```
for x in commands:
   if command in cogs.hi:
      pring(command)
```

Comment: read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916630/list-the-commands-in-a-discord-py-cog/66917144#66917144)